# Php en funcion de javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Buena tardes, alguien que me oriente, quiero ejecutar código PHP desde una función en js, puedo realizar eso.

He intentado y solo me arroja el resultado en un input text, pero no me manda la alert puedo hacer esto, De antemano gracias.

```
 function folio_generate()
  {
    alert('<?php 
        $folios_key = ReceiptData::getAllFolios();
          if(count($folios_key)>0):
            foreach($folios_key as $items):
              $folio = $items->ask;
              if(@$folio=="")
                {
                  $folio = 1;
                } else {
                  $folio++;
                }
                echo "Folio generado: ".$folio;
            endforeach;
          endif;

      ?>');

  }
```

Comment: cada que intentan combinar `PHP` y `JS` un gatito muere :C, así que por favor, **¡No lo hagas!**, dale un vistazo a esto: [**AJAX**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), es la mejor manera de trabajar `PHP` y `JS` en conjunto

Comment: @Jorius, solo para dar más luz al asunto porque puede que no haya quedado totalmente claro: un gatito muere, **pero asesinado y entre terribles sufrimientos**, no es una muerte sencilla y natural.

Answer (score 3):

te recomiendo que uses ajax para que logres tu objetivo.

```
$.ajax({
url:'miphp.php?codigo=1',
type:'post',
data:'{nombre:"Carlos"}',
success:function(r){
//hacer algo
   console.log(r);
}
});
```

codigo en php - file:miphp.php

```
$codigo = $_GET["codigo"];
switch ($codigo){
case 1:
     //Llama a tu funcion php
     echo hacerAlgoPhp();
     break;
case 2:
// ...
}

function hacerAlgoPhp(){
return "hola ".$_POST["nombre"];
}
```

De esta forma puedes ejecutar código php desde javascript

Comment: Si desarrollas un poco más la respuesta con un ejemplo sobre como operar en el callback `success` con la respuesta recibida, te ganas mi upvote! ;)

Comment: Ok, solo que en mi codigo no tengo la necesidad de utlizar $_GET, ya que en mi codigo mando a llamar mi funcion php **$folios_key = ReceiptData::getAllFolios();** ahora en ajax si no pongo ?codigo=1 solo mi ruta php, como seria el data y success ;) - @jose

Comment: @Ever, ería de la misma manera. Si no necesitas enviar ninguna variable, no lo hagas, solo llama al `PHP` que se encarga de retornar los datos y utiliza estos en el `callback` (success).

Comment: Si en tu archivo php solo habrá una función, no será necesario que uses el get. Sin embargo es muy útil cuando en un archivo php manejas mas de una función. Ya que desde ajax no se puede invocar una específicamente una función, sino se ejecuta todo el archivo php(si quieres intentas).

Comment: Hola @josefranciscosotteccani. Hay algunas cosas en tu código que debes arreglar. Dentro del objeto que pasas a la función `$.ajax` para separar las propiedades estás usando punto y coma al final en vez de comas y al parámetro `type` le das el valor con un signo de igual en vez de dos puntos.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo arregle! (:L) suele pasar cuando contestas desde el movil xD. jajaaj discúlpenme!

Comment: Suele pasar @joseFranciscoasotteccani. Es normal cuando se escribe código dejar el móvil. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Esta respuesta es solo como complemento de la respuesta dada por @joseFranciscoSotteccani. Como bien dice él en su respuesta, lo mejor en tu caso es usar `Ajax`.

La razón de usar `Ajax` no es un capricho. Aparte de no querer que un inocente gatito muera, el código que corre en el servidor debe quedar en el servidor, separado del código que corre en el cliente. Esto te permitirá tener tu código más controlado en cada entorno aparte de hacerlo más mantenible y escalable. Imagina como sería a lo largo del tiempo mantener un código donde el `HTML`, el `CSS`, el `JavaScript` y el `PHP` estuvieran todos mezclados. ¿Cómo sabrías dónde encontrar una funcionalidad específica? ¿Cómo haces debug de manera rápida y eficiente de un código con estas características? Si comienzas un proyecto usando malas prácticas te aseguro que mientras más crezca, junto a él crecerán los problemas y los dolores de cabeza.

En cuanto a tu problema específico, para lograr lo que deseas no debes cambiar casi nada tu código `PHP`. Sólo debes llamarlo mediante `Ajax` y utilizar en `JavaScript` las variables que recibas. Solo debes tener en cuenta que como la variable `$folio` la recibes dentro de un ciclo `for` lo mejor es que guardes todos los valores que devuelve `$items->ask` dentro de un `Array`. Te dejo un ejemplo:

**Código PHP:**

```
$folios_key = ReceiptData::getAllFolios();

$folios_array = array();

if (count($folios_key) > 0) {

    foreach ($folios_key as $items) {

        $folio = $items->ask;

        $folios_array[] = ($folio == "") ? 1 : $folio + 1;

    }

}

echo json_encode($folios_array);
```

**Código JavaScript:**

```
function folio_generate () {

    $.get("path/a/tu/fichero.php", function (folios) {

        alert("Los folios generados son: " + folios.join(", "));

    }, "json");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer un AJAX para tu proposito. Tienes que ver bien que tipo de metodo ocupas, si es una petición `GET` o `POST`

AJAX POST :

```
$.ajax({
   url:'miphp.php';
   type : 'POST';
   dataType : 'json',
   data:'{nombre:"Carlos"}';
   success:function(r){
      console.log(r);
   },
   error: function(error) {
   }
});
```

PHP PARA AJAX POST

El return debe ser un json, por lo tanto en PHP ocupa `json_encode($result)`;

AJAX GET

```
var nombre = "Carlos";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "miphp.php",
    data: nombre,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data)
    },
    error : function(error){
    }
});
```

Comment: Una duda @sioesi ¿Por qué es necesario que devuelva un `JSON` la llamada `POST`?

Comment: @ElChiniNet JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) es el tipo de objeto que maneja javascript, en los eventos AJAX se intenta siempre comunicar un lenguaje o codigo de lado cliente con un codigo de lado servidor. Para poder comunicar ambos lenguajes, se utilizan objetos json, tambien xml en ocaciones, pero esta es la forma optima de trabajar codigo php con javascript

Comment: Depende del dato que necesites, puedes obtener un `HTML` un `JSON`, un `XML`, un `Script` o un `String`. ¿Mi duda es por qué afirmas que necesariamente tiene que ser un `JSON`?

Comment: No es que sea necesariamente un JSON, es una manera optima de recibir datos desde el servidor para asi manipularlos, un arreglo, un arreglo de objetos, un objeto.. no es mas facil trabajarlos asi?

Comment: Depende, si necesitas que te devuelva una cadena lo mejor en mi opinión es que te devuelva un `String`. Me parece que todo depende de lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: yo prefiero siempre recibir un json, si necesito una cadena.. armaria una variable php `$result = array('error' => 0, 'mensaje' => '')`, dependiendo de la funcion que haga o necesite, llenaria ese arreglo con datos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60395/discussion-between-elchininet-and-sioesi).